# drive slowly or drive more slowly?

Tags: adverbs, comparative

Would it be wrong or unnatural/awkward if I asked somebody to "Drive slowly! You're driving too fast". Instead of "Drive more slowly! You're driving too fast"

Comment: I'm not sure why, but "Drive more slowly" sounds weird to me (native speaker, Maritimes). I would say "Drive slower".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on context. *Drive slowly* would be appropriate if driving at a normal speed is unsafe, for example in a zone where pedestrian traffic and vehicular traffic are both permitted. *Drive more slowly* would be appropriate if the speaker feels the current speed is too fast. This could be a request to slow from 110 km/h to 100 km/h.

The most common expression in my experience is "slow down", which is synonymous with the second instruction.

Answer (score 3):

The adverb [*slowly* is commonly used to modify the verb *drive*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drive+slowly%2Cdrive+more+slowly&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3), and I see no reasons why it can't be used without being modified itself.

Comment: Certainly it can – just not in the context given in the question. As Peter says in his answer, in that context, the idiomatic phrase which would be used instead is ‘slow down’. But in other contexts, it would be fine; for example, “Studies have shown that people drive more slowly when trees are planted on kerb strips” is perfectly natural.